# Use user input string to build function in server()?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a shiny app that uses `textInput()` to define 2 variable names (let's call them `x=u` and `y=v`), and an equation associated with each (let's say `dx=1-u*v` and `dy=(u*(1-v)`).

That is, I can define reactive strings `x`,`y`,`dx`, and `dy` in `server()` to get at those strings.

I would like to take those strings and define a function that looks like

```
function(u,v) {
 return(c(1-u*v,u*(1-v)))
}
```

which, in a plain ol' R script, I can do using `eval(parse(text=paste0(...)))`, however I can't find a way to do this in `server()` when these things are reactive.

Here's an example with two eval() lines commented out. I'd like to create `parms` and `fun` based on user input and NOT have them hard-coded.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Parse list of parameters into parms 
  #### NEXT LINE DOESN'T WORK
  #eval(parse(text=paste0("parms <- c(", input$ps,")")))
  #### Instead, I can only hard-code parms...
  parms <- c(a=3,b=2,c=2)

  # Define fun() to calculate derivatives using parms
  #
  # Ex: If x=u, y=v, dx=-u + a/(1+v^b), and dy=-v + a/(1+u^c)
  #     then we'd want to define the function
  #
  # fun <- function(u,v,ps) { with(as.list(ps),{c(-u + a/(1+v^b), -v + a/(1+u^c))})}
  #
  ### THIS NEXT LINE DOES NOT WORK
  #eval(parse(text=paste0("fun <- function(","input$x",",", input$y,", ps) { with(as.list(ps),{c(",,",",,")}) }")))
  ## Instead, I must hard code it as...
  fun <- function(u,v,ps) { with(as.list(ps),{c(-u + a/(1+v^b), -v + a/(1+u^c))})}

  # Once fun() works, define fun2 for use with deSolve solvers...  
  fun2 <- function(t,z,p) { list(fun(z[1],z[2],p)) }

  # numerical solution
  out <- ode(times=seq(0,10,length=150),y=c(1/2,1),func=fun2,parms=parms);

  # plot
  output$PPlot <- renderPlot({ plot(out[,-1],type="l",lty=1,lwd=2,xlab=input$x,ylab=input$y) })  
}


ui <- pageWithSidebar(  headerPanel("Example"),
  sidebarPanel(
    h4("Plot"),
    ## Reformat to make these horizontal

    inputPanel(condition = "input.userAction == 'setup'",
                     textInput("x", label = h5("x-axis variable"), value = "u"),
                     textInput("y", label = h5("y-axis variable"), value = "v"),
                     textInput("dx", label = h5("dx/dt"), value = "-u + a/(1+v^b)"),
                     textInput("dy", label = h5("dy/dt"), value = "-v + a/(1+u^c)"),
                     textInput("ps", label = h5("Parameters"), value = "a=3,b=2,c=2")
    )
  ),

  mainPanel(h1("Plot Numerical Solution starting at (1/2,1)"),
            plotOutput("PPlot")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Did you try to do it in observe and reactiveValues? smt like  `need_val=reactiveValues(parms)
observe({
  eval(parse(text=paste0("need_val$parms <- c(", input$ps,")")))
  })` and then use `need_val$parms` instead of `parms`

Comment: In general the `eval(parse(text=...))` thing works, however its nicer to do it with `as.formula()`. The thing is you need to put everything into a reactive context like `observe` or `reactive` otherwise it will be executed only once, when you start the app.

Comment: I was able to fix parms by just defining a function that is only called inside a reactive context, but it's the function that was causing issues. I'll give it another go and report back if I make any progress.

Comment: This works, but is more cumbersome than I'd like (i.e., I'd love a cleaner solution if it exists).  Make two functions 
`fn   <- function() { eval(parse(text=paste0("fun <<- function(",input$x,",",input$y,", ps) { with(as.list(ps),{c(",input$dx,",",input$dy,")}) }")))}` 
and
`prms <- function() { eval(parse(text=paste0("parms <- c(",input$ps,")"))) }`
Then call in renderPlot() `plot(ode(times=seq(0,10,length=150),y=c(1/2,1),
             func=function(t,z,p) { fn(); list(fun(z[1],z[2],p)) },
             parms=prms())[,-1], type="l",lty=1,lwd=2,xlab=input$x,ylab=input$y) }) `